# Piped command is failing inside docker container

Tags: docker

I'm executing this command from docker host which is finally not giving me any error on stdout. And completes successfully on prompt but doesn't executes what it is supposed to do inside container.
Can someone please help me identify what am i doing wrong?

```
docker exec -dt SPSSC /bin/bash -c "grep -ril 'LOCALIZATION_ENABLED="false"' /opt/tpa/confd/config/* | grep -v 'diameter' | xargs sed -i 's/LOCALIZATION_ENABLED="false"/LOCALIZATION_ENABLED="true"/g'"
```

Comment: Maybe start by removing the `-d` from `docker exec` so that you can see any output produced by your command?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Nice suggestion. Removing -d pastes a sed error: 
sed: no input files
What do you suggest next?

Comment: Well, the obvious first test is to see if `grep -ril 'LOCALIZATION_ENABLED="false"' /opt/tpa/confd/config/*` is generating any output.